# iOS Over The Air distribution with iOS8 (iOS 7 is working fine)

Tags: xcode, ios8, over-the-air

I'm using over the air distribution to distribute my App to test devices. This worked fine in the past.

After upgrading one device to iOS 8 I've got the following error message:
Unable to Download Application
"Your Application" could not be downloaded at this time.

The distribution and download in iOS 7 devices is still working fine. Installation via iTunes or Xcode works also on the iOS 8 device. So it should not be an issue with the App?

Has Apple changed something with the over the air distribution?

Many thanks,
Stefan

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only one with this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772664/enterprise-app-update-distribution-on-ios-8

Answer (score 2):

We are having the same issue - our internal app store that we used to distribute to developers does not work with IOS 8, but it works with all versions prior.

We solved out problem and it was something that may or may not work for you.

It seems that IOS 8 is less forgiving than IOS 7 and prior and one of our developers stumbled on it.

We had to correct 2 items.

1. In the plist file there was an embedded special character that we did not see that got removed.  We also had to make sure that " was not the italicized version that many editors will substitute.
2. The icons referenced in the plist file had to be replaced.  We must have had some very minor corruption in the images we published to our site, but it was enough to prevent it from finishing the install.

Verify these 2 items and give it a try to see if that fixes your issue.