# Enterprise-distributed app won't install on some devices

Tags: ios, iphone, enterprise-distribution

I have developed an iPhone app for enterprise distribution.

I have deployed the .ipa file to a webserver, where it is downloaded over HTTP Secure.

I can install the app just fine this way. However, other people are unable to install it. After getting the "Do you wish to install [AppName]?" prompt, nothing happens. The app icon is not added to the home screen and the download doesn't start.

These devices are the exact same model as my own device (iPhone 5S) and are also running the same version of iOS (8.0.2).

Are there any likely culprits for this problem? What can cause the app to install properly on my own device but fail on other (in my view) identical devices?

Comment: what type of provisioning profile are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. I had to change the bundle identifier in my plist file.

So change

```
<key>bundle-identifier</key>
<string>com.mycom.MyApp</string>
```

to

```
<key>bundle-identifier</key>
<string>com.mycom.MyApp.somethingElse</string>
```

(Got the answer from here: [Enterprise App Update Distribution on iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772664/enterprise-app-update-distribution-on-ios-8))