# iOS Enterprise Distribution - always get the same build

Tags: ios, caching, versioning, bundle-identifier, enterprise-distribution

I have enterprise distribution working. The problem is that when I create new builds and replace the .ipa on the server with a new version, it somehow always loads version 1.0 of the app.

Here is the plist file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>http://myapp.com/app/MyApp.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.myapp.myappenterprise</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.1</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>My App</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've tried:

Clearing cache in mobile Safari.

Made sure version # of app is increased (1.1)

Made sure build # of app is increased.

Delete app from server and uploaded fresh copy of new version.

Changed bundle-version in plist to 1.1.

Set no-cache policy on HTML file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
...
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://myapp.com/app/enterprise.plist">Install</a>
```

Any ideas on how in the world am I still getting version 1.0 installed when I install through Safari, even though I have created new builds and replaced the .ipa file on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add  a 'display-image' and 'full-size-image' as described [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1829415&seqNum=16).
Or you can try to fix this issue by 'faking' the bundle identifier as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25948839/1600405).

Comment: The actual issue was that I had a bad link in my html file. Marking this correct as it sent me down the path.