# Xcode Server OTA App Installs iOS 8 Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode-server

I have the same issue that is mentioned here: [Enterprise App Update Distribution on iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772664/enterprise-app-update-distribution-on-ios-8)

I'm not able to install the App on one of my iOS 8 devices and the log prints the following error:

> LoadExternalDownloadManifestOperation: Ignore manifest download, already have bundleID: com.mycom.MyApp

The fix suggested says to change the bundle-identifier of the plist in the manifest. If I'm using Xcode Server on Yosemite, where is the plist file located I need to change?

Xcode Server OTA Installation Screen:

[image: Xcode Server OTA Web Page]

Comment: Is the previous version of App already installed on device? Or some App you installed using same AppId, possibly from App Store?

Comment: A previous version was on the device, but it was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you will need to change the bundleID inside of Xcode.

Click on your app in Xcode, and then target.
You will see you bundleID "com.something.something", change this or append something to the end and then it should work.

Downside it seems people who already have the app installed, will see another icon.
I think this will have to be the cause until this is fixed.

Comment: No, it is not the bundle ID in Xcode but the one used in a plist by OTA installation configuration.

Comment: hmm, I havn't used the server in a little while. 
Search your computer for a manifest.plist file in the Server Configs and edit it there.

You should be able to locate that file by looking at the URL you visit when you download the app if its a local address