# iOS Development build suddenly not downloading on a device who's UDID is registered

Tags: ios, xamarin, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have an iOS App that's provisioned with a developer provisioning profile.  My iPhone 6's UDID is registered and has been downloading this from a link where the IPA is hosted on Dropbox.  This has been working for months, literally since bout February.  Suddenly it stopped downloading.  Now when I tap the link within my phone and tap "Install" no app downloads and no error message is given.  I know my provisioning profiles are valid and working because I have about 20 devices in this apple developer account and they are all able to download the app successfully.

Note:  I've even used Dropbox's version control to revert the IPA file back to one that worked in the past and my phone can still no longer download the IPA.  This leads me to believe there's something that has changed with Apple's provisioning system since the recent WWDC or that something is wrong with my phone.  I'm considering backing up and resetting my phone.

My Phone is an iPhone 6 with iOS 8.3 (12F70)

----------Edit-----------

```
Jun 13 12:39:19 Leet-Sauce itunesstored[98] <Warning>: LoadExternalDownloadManifestOperation: Ignore manifest download, already have bundleID: com.milllife.milla with phase: SSDownloadPhaseWaiting
Jun 13 12:39:21 Leet-Sauce CLTM[20] <Error>: CLTM: _subscription 0x0, _subscribedChannels 0x0
Jun 13 12:39:21 Leet-Sauce kernel[0] <Notice>: IOReturn AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver::getIOSurfaceFromID(DestinationOrSource, M2ScalerCSCRequest *) 3645 (*ppBuffCS) is NULL
Jun 13 12:39:21 Leet-Sauce kernel[0] <Notice>: transformGeneral failed (0xe00002f0).
Jun 13 12:39:23 Leet-Sauce MobileMail[633] <Warning>: Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received permission from the user to badge the application
```

Looks like the "Ignore manifest download, already have bundleID" part is key.  So it appears my app is stuck in a funky state where I already have an app with that bundleID, yet It's not easily visible on my phone.  [This post Seems relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772664/enterprise-app-update-distribution-on-ios-8)

Comment: Have you tried using a different phone?

Comment: Yep, we have about 20 iPhones/iPads on our account.  All of them work except for mine.

Comment: If all the iPhones have the same iOS version, then I think just resetting your phone will solve the problem.

Comment: I agree, I'm just wondering what's really going on and if it's solvable before I go and do that.

Comment: You need to look at the device's console when you try to do the install to see what the real problem is.  Post what you see, and then people might be able to help.

Comment: Good call, not sure why I didn't think of that.  I'm updating the OP with the details from XCode Console

Comment: Yes, you seem to have been struck by the iOS 8 bug where the device thinks you already have the app installed, so it won't let you re-install it.  You're link to the relevant post is correct. You have two options  - do a re-install of iOS on the device, or hack your plist to use a different bundle id to trick it into doing the install.   I prefer the first option if at all possible, since the second is a pain to maintain if you generate your plist through a CI process.  Good luck.