# Enterprise distribution version won't install on device iOS9

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, enterprise

Last week before installing the new Xcode 7 I created an ipa version of my app and uploaded it, the users downloaded it and it run just fine. Now, after updating the Xcode to version 7, I'm uploading the new ipa and the users who download it can't install.

[image]

Does anyone knows what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28727958/1138498) post and did what he said and it worked fine after that. Try it.