# iOS 10 beta: Not able to install enterprise distribution build from site/url

Tags: ios, beta, ios10

We are not able to install app from url in iOS 10.0 Beta. It is giving popup "Would you like to install app "xyz"?" Once, we click Install it does nothing. We are using enterprise distribution.

Device:
iPad Mini

Version:
10.0 (14A5261v)

Request you to help

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here, [this bug exists since iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772664/enterprise-app-update-distribution-on-ios-8), but even worse in iOS 10.

I've reported a bug to Apple.

Comment: Right now we are using Xamarin tool for development and have also ask to Apple team. Let's keep updated here if anyone find any solution.

Answer (score 2):

According to engineers at WWDC it's a bug related to iOS 10 Beta 1, should be fixed in the future betas.

Right now you can only install an app once, it will fail if you try to install an app with the same bundle id. A factory reset will let you install the app again or a using a new bundle id will also work until Apple fixes this.

So if you really need to install an update of an app (as the first install will always work) doing a factory reset of the phone or using a new bundle id seems to be the best solution right now.

Update : this seems to be fixed in Beta 2

Comment: I reset the iPad and then tried to reinstall the apps. But still the issue was as it is. It's showing alert to install but after that no process start.

Comment: Did you restore a backup ? You have to do a factory reset and do not restore a backup

Answer (score 2):

I can get an enterprise app to install once on iOS 10 Beta 1 if I factory reset the device.  It will install exactly once each time I factory reset the device.

Comment: I reset the iPad and then tried to reinstall the apps. But still the issue was as it is. It's showing alert to install but after that no process start.

Answer (score 0):

I took the update for official beta release iOS 10.0 from Apple and the issue has been fixed. Now am able to download the app number of time.

Comment: Yes it has been fixed in Beta 2