# Over the air (OTA) installation fails for iOS8 app using itms-services URL

Tags: ios, ios8, ota

For all prior versions of iOS, I've used the itms-services:// URL to install test iOS apps over the air (OTA). Now, all my devices with iOS8 fail when trying to install apps using this approach. Example URL:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://myWebsite/myApp/myApp.plist
```

Summary of problem:

1. The Safari browser used to launch the install from a web page does
   not exit to the main screen showing the app installing as before in prior iOS versions
2. The application never successfully installs. It installs, but is left as a greyed out icon, and the app will not launch.
3. This problem does not occur on existing iOS7 devices, with identical URL.

Comment: Possibly related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772664/enterprise-app-update-distribution-on-ios-8

Comment: I've just tested my app via testflightapp and it works fine.If I'm not wrong that service uses the same distribution way.

Comment: have you looked at the console output to see what (if any) errors are being reported? I've used this method to track down issues with the `itms-services` manifests a few times in iOS7 and it was very helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the Beta5 and GM versions of iOS8.

Over at Buildozer we've found a workaround: change the bundle identifier of the app in the manifest file. (More details: https://buildozer.io/ios8)

A workaround that doesn't involve changing the manifest files is to restore the entire device from backup, however we feel the manifest 'hack' is less disruptive to users.

Comment: No, it's unfortunately NOT fixed with iOS 8.0.2 - I'm still able to reproduce the error on that release.

Comment: Hi. Had a look at the link above, https://buildozer.io/ios8. it indicates adding -iOS8 "somewhere". Could you be more specific, is the itms link used to download the ipa file or the plist file itself? I have this issues. I have 160 people that are in a mixed state. Some running iOS8.1 and lower, some that can and cannot download our App. Very strange. No pattern other than phones are largely ok, but iPads are in the main, the problem. Help?

Comment: Still not fixed in 8.1.3...
Thanks for the workaround

Answer (score 7):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25994559/1894389) helped me to fix the issue. It seems that for iOS8 you have to include in the `assets` key of the manifest `.plist` file the `display-image` and `full-size-image` keys. They were available in Xcode 5 when saving an archive for enterprise and add-hoc deployment, but not required.

I have created a gist on github with the template for the [install-manifet.plist](https://gist.github.com/alexcristea/4d922de3d416910dc847) file.
The original post is available on http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1829415&seqNum=16.

Comment: This worked for me one time only for iOS 8.1. Enterprise acc distribution. After that it never worked again.

Answer (score 4):

As far as we know, this issue still not be solved in iOS 8.1, and we found that this solution will cause some side effect. After iOS 7.0.x devices use this method to install inHouse apps, although the app installed successful but the home screen left a black square, and can't be deleted.

You have to separate the install method between iOS8 and other iOS versions, which means you change the install method in iOS8, and keep the original install method in other version.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. In my case the problem was fixed when:

- the plist was served from HTTPS
- the IPA was served from HTTPS from the same domain as the plist
- full-size-image and display-image are present in the plist

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. Our cause was that TestFlight had installed the bundle previously. It seems that TestFlight has (had) a profile installed, and only it could update the apps, even if they were uninstalled and deleted.

A workaround was to add some suffix to the bundle identifier in the plist.

This of course caused another problem, that a secondary icon was showing until download was complete and the IPA was unpacked and matched with the app already on device.

BIG NOTICE: This is only a problem with iOS8, so you better check the user-agent during the download. It will be itunesd and will contain the exact iOS version.