# Install app from web server

Tags: ios, iphone

Can I generate a IPA file of my App with the iOS Developer Program($99/year), upload the IPA to my web server, make a link of It, and then Install It on my Iphone by visiting my web server and click on the link?

Or must I have the enterprise distribution for this?

I simply want to Install my app without publishing It on appstore.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25994559/1565335) might be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $99 program only allows you to public install your app via the AppStore. You can always distribute a AdHoc version of you app as long the UDID of the device that you want to install it on is registered in the provisioning profile.

The Enterprise profile is only ment for distributing app to employees. The license does not allow distribution to non employees.

Comment: Additionally with ad hoc there is a limit of 100 devices it can be installed onto

Comment: @rckoenes: If you look at the link that Azat provided, It seems like I just can create a IPA-file and link to It?

Comment: @Bryan the link is correct, but this is an AdHoc build, thus you will need to have the UDID's of the device you want the app to installed on before hand. Also you are restricted to 100 registered device per year. –